# Increasing Width of tabs in Tab layout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter, android-tablayout

[image]

Hi All,

I am working on Android Material Design.

When I add mode tabs to my adapter, the text gets distorted breaking into two places as shown in figure.
My code:

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ListContentFragment(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new TileContentFragment(), "Screen 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new CardContentFragment(), "Screen 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new ListContentFragment(), "Screen 3");
        adapter.addFragment(new TileContentFragment(), "Screen 4");
        adapter.addFragment(new CardContentFragment(), "Screen 5");


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

My XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:tint="@color/white"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navheader"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How to increase tab width so as to ensure 6that Home, Screen1, Screen 2 etc come in a single line i,e with more width and not in two lines?

Comment: Set tabMode to Scrollable and try.

Comment: post your xml here as well

Comment: I have posted my XML as well.

Comment: replace with this  :--><android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 app:tabMode="scrollable"
                />

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set app:tabMode="scrollable" for android.support.design.widget.TabLayout inside layout file

Answer (score 3):

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. How to change Tab Color when we navigate from Home to Screen 1 to Screen 2 and so on? Say I want everything to be orange when I am on screen two. How can I do that?

Comment: you need change the theme

Comment: Thanks. Should I dynamically set that?

Comment: you can set onPageChanged

Answer (score 3):

Programatically set

```
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

**OR**

XML

```
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

Please note down if it doesn't meet you requirement

Comment: I also need the following:
 Changing the color or theme when I navigate from Home to Screen 1 or from Screen 1 to Screen 2. How can I do that? Can you point me to an example

Comment: app:tabGravity="fill" not work for  app:tabMode="scrollable".i works only for  app:tabMode="fixed"